# What are the characters in this seal?

Tags: character-identification, seal, reading

I've been trying to decipher this seal from a silkscreen painting by using guoxuedashi and other websites.

[image: seal]

I believe the first character is 林.
The second looks similar to 鹿 but I have no idea.

The last two characters are difficult to make out, so I've tried to highlight what lines are visible but had to do a lot of guesswork on the last character.

[image: highlighted seal]

I would appreciate any help with interpreting the seal.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the content of this seal might be "林散之印", with the upper right character being "林", the upper right being "散", lower left "之" and lower right "印". The following is the picture obtained by searching "[林散之印](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%E6%9E%97%E6%95%A3%E4%B9%8B%E5%8D%B0&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7x5Of8Yj0AhWHy4sBHfgxATUQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1340&bih=692&dpr=1.38)" on Google.

[image: 林散之印]

Sanzhi Lin ([林散之](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hans/%E6%9E%97%E6%95%A3%E4%B9%8B)) is a Chinese calligrapher and painter who was born in 1898 and died in 1989. He was good at cursive calligraphy ([草书](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/%E8%8D%89%E4%B9%A6)).

I don’t know the specific age of the silkscreen painting in question, so I’m not sure if he had paintings or calligraphy works on it.

I hope that helps!